# JS: Attach body onload cross browser (methods comparison)

Tags: javascript

I have examined [Dean Edward's `onload` post](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/) and have a question: what's wrong with this `onload` attaching method? Where and why can it fail? And when is it safe to use this simpler function?

```
function addLoadEvent(func){
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if(typeof window.onload != 'function'){
        window.onload = func;
    }else{
        window.onload = function(){
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is just chaining. To use multiple handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of Dean's post isn't about how to hook the `window.load` event, but rather how to hook a useful event ***prior*** to `window.load`. `window.load` happens very, very late in the page load cycle (after **all** resources, including all images, are fully loaded). If your page has any significant resources and you wait until `window.load` to hook up your event handlers, your users are likely to start doing things before your handlers are hooked up.

Note that Dean's article was written in 2006. The modern practice is to simply put your script just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. As long as your script is *after* any elements it refers to, the elements will be accessible to you. That way, you hook things up very early on indeed.

Example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/iviwal/2)):

HTML:

```
<p>This page has a big image on it, to help demonstrate
  <code>window.load</code>'s very late arrival.
  Note that this paragraph started out black, but was
  turned green <em>immediately</em> on page load.
  This demonstrates that the paragraph was available
  to the code at the end of the page.
</p>
<img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1110/sh2136s_block900.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 20em;">
```

JavaScript (just before `</body>` end tag):

```
(function() {
  var first;

  function hookLoad(handler) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener("load", handler, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
      window.attachEvent("onload", handler);
    }
  }

  display("Script running at end of page; turning paragraph green.");
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.color = "green";

  hookLoad(function() {
    display("First load handler");
  });

  hookLoad(function() {
    display("Second load handler");
  });

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p'),
        now = new Date().getTime();
    msg = now + ": " + msg;
    if (first) {
      msg += " (delayed by " + (now - first) + "ms)";
    }
    else {
      first = now;
    }
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

If you can't do that (put the script at the end of the `body` element) for some reason, then tricks like Dean's start being useful, but I'd strongly recommend *against* DIY "DOM loaded" handling; instead, use a good, well-maintained library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) and use their "ready" event. By leveraging the ongoing work put into those libraries, you can instead focus on what you're trying to do with your own page/app.

---

References:

- [YUI's best practices for speeding up your website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google on when DOM elements are accessible](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41) (and why their library doesn't have a "DOM ready" event)

---

[Re `window.load` specifically: You don't have to resort to your trick, just use `addEventListener` (if the browser supports it, all do except older IE versions) or `attachEvent` (older IE). See `hookLoad` in the example above. Those allow multiple handlers for an event.]